# MySQL: Calculate width date in column

Tags: mysql, date

I want to define a cron that freqently delete specific data from a MySQL column if date in date_added column is older than 60 days, but don't find any infomation if MySQL supports calculation width date. Is that possible and if yes how to do?

```
DELETE FROM 
vcount 
WHERE date_added - 60 days
```

date_added == datetime == 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html DATE_ADD() or DATE_SUB()

Comment: If you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

assuming your date_added is a valid date  column you can use date_sub

```
DELETE FROM 
vcount 
WHERE date_sub(date_added, INTERVAL 60 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either date_add() or date_sub() functions:

```
where date_added < date_add(curdate(),INTERVAL -60 DAY)
```

or

```
where date_added < date_sub(curdate(),INTERVAL 60 DAY)
```

(many prefer to always use date_add() using a negative interval for subtraction)

Answer (score 0):

use DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL value interval)

date :  Required. The date to be modified

value : Required. The value of the time/date interval to subtract. Both positive and negative values are allowed

interval:   Required. The type of interval to subtract. Can be one of the following

values:

MICROSECOND

SECOND

MINUTE

HOUR

DAY

WEEK

MONTH

QUARTER

YEAR

SECOND_MICROSECOND

MINUTE_MICROSECOND

MINUTE_SECOND

HOUR_MICROSECOND

HOUR_SECOND

HOUR_MINUTE

DAY_MICROSECOND

DAY_SECOND

DAY_MINUTE

DAY_HOUR

YEAR_MONTH

```
DELETE FROM 
vcount 
WHERE date_added  < (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY))
```